# Share internet connection among 2 separate interfaces on an ASA

Tags: networking, cisco, cisco-asa, vlan

I am using a Cisco ASA 5505, and my license only permits 2 interfaces, so I have just added a vlan instead. I want to keep this vlan away from the inside network. 
I believe it's something to do with the NATing, or nat exempt setup.I now have outside, inside and my new interface.

Comment: Yes, it's possible for both to use the internet connection while not being allowed to communicate with each other.  What's your config look like, and which software version are you on?

Comment: Hi Shane, I'm on ASA Version 8.2(1)

Comment: I have moved over to an ASA5505 now, and my license only permits 2 interfaces, so I have just added a vlan instead. I believe it's something to do with the NATing, or nat exempt setup.

Comment: When they say two interfaces, they mean VLANs, not the physical interfaces on the ASA.  You can assign the 8 ports across your VLANs as you see fit, although you should probably stick to convention with port 0 assigned to outside, but the rest you can divide between an additional two VLANs (typically inside and dmz).

Answer (score 1):

It is now working. I had to add these lines to the config:

```
nat (DMZ) 0 access-list DMZ_nat0_outbound
nat (DMZ) 1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
access-group DMZ_access_in in interface DMZ
```